# If I call Shell Foo.exe from a VB6 program, and Foo.exe flames out, will my VB6 program flame out too?

Tags: shell, vb6, runtime

I am once again forced to update an archaic vb6 program for reasons that make me want to fling myself into traffic.

I have written a bare bones .Net application that is to be Shelled by the VB6 program under certain circumstances.

Because the .Net program runs in .Net 4.5.2, and my VB6 IDE is on a Windows XP system ( kill me please ), I fully expect it ( the .Net application ) to crash in glorious fashion when the VB6 program calls it to run in the development environment.

Unfortunately that's not happening - what is happening is I am getting a runtime error 5.

This is the call VB6 should be making -

```
Shell """" & App.Path & "\Foo.exe"""
```

That's it. The .Net program in question is a lookless application ( no ui, no console, and that's how it's supposed to be ), whereas the VB6 program has a GUI and makes me want to take up casual alcoholism as a hobby.

The only thing that I can think of is the called program flaming out makes VB6 throw a fit - is that hypothesis correct? If not, what else could be the problem?

Comment: VB6? Not .NET? Seems really late in the game to learn VB6...

Comment: @AustinFrench I know .Net. I know enough about VB6 to not slit my wrists and throat when I'm forced to support these god awful legacy apps. I'm not trying to learn VB6. I'm just updating this stupid program per the clients specifications.

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue if the .net program can run standalone. What does the .Net program do?

Comment: I would suspect that the WIndows XP loader isn't able to even start the .NET process so you're getting a runtime error 5.  A cheap trick would be to copy notepad.exe (or anything else) and rename it as foo.exe so that your VB6 program has something to launch that will work allowing you to carry on testing your VB6 code.

Comment: Just to add some detail.  Because Shell returns a Task Id for the shelled program then the shelled program has to be able to start for it to return successfully.  If your .NET app can't start (because of missing DLLs or whatever) then the Vb runtime will throw Error 5 (not wholy meaningful).  The simple question is will foo.exe work if you just run it separately.

Comment: @OldBoyCoder No it will not, and your answer is the correct one. That does make sense. I tried to run the program alone and got the good old fashioned "Not a valid win32 application" ( even though it runs fine on my more modern system ). So I'm going to say that yes, if the program flames out, your ( my ) vb6 program will flame out too. If you would like to state your comment in the form of an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB6 `Shell` command will raise a runtime error 5 if it can't start the program specified.  If that runtime error is unhandled then your program will halt with a standard VB6 error message for that error.  As stated in the comments the OP's .NET EXE can't be launched on Windows XP (maybe it was built for x64?) so they are getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

.Net 4.5+ isn't supported on XP so I wouldn't expect your app to work. In fact I'm not sure how you even installed 4.5. When I tried it failed at the OS check. I had to target 4.0 as a result.

VB6 won't crash because of your .Net app since it's not the same process. It will get an error as you see, but you just handle that and move on.